# Posting page on all subdomains

Tags: theme-development, subdomains, wp-api

I'm just asking to see if anyone has done this or any ideas how it could be done.

I have 11 Wordpress sites(on a network/multisite, 1 domain and 10 subdomains) that will grow.

I'm in the process of building 1 template to be used on each site (then just change colours, logos, etc...)
Each site follow the same menu structure, just different information.

There are certain pages that I want to publish on all sites, for example, terms & conditions, policies, term dates, etc... these will all come from the main domain

I know there are duplicator plugins, etc... but haven't found anything that does what I want/works with sub domains

I did think whether it could be built in with the template i.e as it builds the menu it gets pages from the main domain tables with a category(share on all) or build a json/xml and inject into each site, or via an api

So information isn't duplicated it comes from the main site

If anyone has any ideas that would be great.

Comment: you can use rest api

Comment: easiest would be to write a plugin that could be network activated, and customizable as needed per theme